# Elliptic K3 surfaces and Lagrangian fibrations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $\pi: S \to \mathbb{P}^{1}$ be an elliptically fibered $K3$ surface. This should be incredibly simple, but I want to show that the restriction of the holomorphic two-form $\sigma$ to a smooth fiber $F$ of $\pi$ is $0$. By working in coordinates, I can prove the analogous fact for the fibration $\pi: E \times E' \to E$, where $E, E'$ are elliptic curves. But I'm hoping for a nudge in the right direction with the more interesting $K3$ case.

I want to reason as follows, but I'm probably too used to thinking about algebraic intersections. If $\sigma$ were an integral class in $H^{1,1}(S)$, it would be Poincare dual to an algebraic curve in $S$, and the restriction would simply be the intersection number with $F$. This is certainly not the case, but $\sigma$ is still Poincare dual to some non-algebraic $2$-cycle in $S$ and I want to show this intersects trivially with $F$? Or is there just a much easier way to go about this?

Comment: A two-form vanishes on **any** curve.

Comment: It can't quite be this simple, can it? This would say that any smooth curve in a symplectic surface is a Lagrangian submanifold. Am I mistaken?

Comment: It is indeed this simple, any curve in a symplectic surface is Lagrangian.

Comment: Why exactly does a two-form restrict to zero on any curve? It is not for purely dimension reasons. It restricts to a multiple of the fundamental class of the curve, but I don't see why it is necessarily zero.

Thanks for your help. So I guess the (smooth) fibers of a Lagrangian fibration are necessarily Abelian varieties. But any curve in a symplectic surface is a Lagrangian submanifold. Is this right? I think this was my main confusion here...

Comment: @Benighted: A holomorphic two-form has type $(2, 0)$. The only non-zero two-forms on a curve have type $(1, 1)$.

Comment: Of course. Thank you! So indeed there are algebraic $(1,1)$-classes that may restrict non-trivially to curves, but no $(2,0)$ or $(0,2)$ classes.

Comment: @Benighted: Yes. For example, the Kähler form.